# Mysql implicit conversion when comparing date column and datetime/time string

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a table with a `Date` column. It has a row where `my_date` column's value is `2017-11-24`

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE my_date = '2017-11-24 00:00:00'` returns that row.

While `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE my_date = '2017-11-24 00:00:01'` does not.

From mysql doc; [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) says

> If one of the arguments is a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column and the
>   other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp
>   before the comparison is performed. This is done to be more
>   ODBC-friendly. This is not done for the arguments to IN().

If I am interpreting this correctly, in the second query, the constant on right side would be implicitly casted to `Date` field

The [second page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html) for casting says -

> Conversion to a DATE value takes fractional seconds into account and
>   rounds the time part. For example, '1999-12-31 23:59:59.499' becomes
>   '1999-12-31', whereas '1999-12-31 23:59:59.500' becomes '2000-01-01'.

The example shows `1999-12-31 23:59:59.499 -> 1999-12-31`. I understand explicit casting is preferred, but I am wondering why mysql chose to typecast the column value instead of constant or if there's something else happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are interpreting the docs correctly. The first page you quote is about comparing a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` to a constant. You are comparing a `DATE` to a constant, so [this logic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html) should apply:

> Conversion of DATE values:
>
> Conversion to a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value adds a time part of '00:00:00' because the DATE value contains no time information.

So it's like comparing `'2017-11-24 00:00:00' = '2017-11-24 00:00:01'` which sensibly returns false.

Comparing DATEs to DATETIMEs/TIMESTAMPs is similar to comparing an int to a double in that the implicit conversion applies to the *less precise* value. You would not expect `42` to match `42.1`, and likewise you shouldn't expect `2017-11-24` to match `2017-11-24 00:00:01`.